# Wrapping an IMG and Div inside a container

Tags: html, sass

I have parent div img-control and 2 child nested divs img-holder and div (.builder is the img class).

I am trying to get the .builder img to fill the img-holder div but protrude out of the top by x%. You'll see the image attached of what I'm trying to achieve with the persons head cut off. In simple terms, I want z-index 1 on the IMG and for the IMG to overflow out of the top.

```
    .img-control{
        display: flex;
    }

    .img-holder{
        flex-basis: 50%;
        width: 228px;
        height: 255px;
        background-color: var(--primary-color);
        margin: 3.4rem 0rem 5rem 1rem;
        overflow: visible;
        position: relative;
    }

    .img-holder:before{
        content: "";
        display: block;
        padding-top: 120%;
    }

    .builder{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;

    }

    .div{
        flex-basis: 50%;
        &__bg{
            
            &--mint{
                width: 228px;
                height: 255px;
                background-color: var(--primary-color);
                margin: 3.4rem 1rem 5rem 0rem;    
            }
    
        }

            &__copy{
                padding: 3rem 1rem 0rem 1rem;
                color: #336B91; 
                display: block;
            }
    }
```

I have tried experimenting with a variation of the inputs defined above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the desired effect of the image protruding out of the top of the .img-holder div, you can set the z-index of the image to 1, and give it a negative margin-top value that is equal to the desired overflow. This way, the image will be positioned in front of the .img-holder div and will overflow out of the top.

```
.builder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: -10%;
}
```

This will cause the image to overflow out of the top by 10%. You can adjust this value to fit your specific needs.